# SQL CMD Mode Issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqlcmd

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER on

declare @source_server_name sysname
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tmp;

create table #tmp(
id int identity(1,1),
server sysname
)

insert into #tmp values('C:\Users\sghosh\Desktop')

select @source_server_name = server from #tmp where id = 1
--select * from #tmp


:setvar source_server_name @source_server_name

:setvar scrpt "\testing.sql"

:r $(source_server_name)$(scrpt)
```

I am getting the error

> A fatal scripting error occurred. Cannot find directory in the path
>   specified for ":r" command.

Please suggest with code.

Comment: This looks like the SQL Server user does not have access to your desktop folder.  Try putting the file in a folder accessible to whatever account SQL Server is using.

Answer (score 2):

You have an order of operations problem here. You are expecting SQLCMD (which runs first) to use variables you define in T-SQL (which doesn't run until after SQLCMD is finished). Try a simpler script to demonstrate this:

```
DECLARE @x VARCHAR(32) = 'string x';

:setvar x @x
:setvar y "string y"

SELECT '$(x)','$(y)';
```

Result:

```
@x       string y
```

Basically, you can't tell SQLCMD to use values from your #temp table, because it doesn't exist yet.